# How to search and copy information from two tables in SQLite on Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

Beginner here.

I have this problem: I have two tables in my database. Table Customers and table Parcels. The program should find a customers id number from table Customers, when the user types the customers name. Then copy the customers id to table Parcels under column "customer_id".

Here is what I have done, but NetBeans gives me the Index out of bound exception. I have also tried another way, but then the program thinks I am trying to access a column by the name of the users feed. (I have created the tables in another if clause) What should I do differently? Here is my code:

```java
            } if (feed.equals("4")) {
                System.out.println("Add tracking number: ");
                String tn = input.nextLine();
                PreparedStatement a = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Parcels(tracknumb,cust_id) VALUES(?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                a.setString(1, u);

                System.out.println("Add customer name: ");
                String nameid = input.nextLine();

                PreparedStatement y = db.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM Customers WHERE name= ?");


                y.setString(2, nameid);
                ResultSet rl = y.executeQuery(nameid);
                if(rl.next()) {
                    int id = rl.getInt(nameid);

                    a.setInt(2, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is within your SQL requests.

You're trying to insert `?` into one of your values in the database, but keep in mind that `?` is something unknown to the SQLite database.

If you're trying to insert an empty value, insert `NULL`. If you're trying to insert something from somewhere else, try `{0}`, and add `, yourValue`.

Try this out and see if it works.

Note: If you still want to use questions marks within your database, type `\"?\"` or `'?'`. This way, if you've configured your table to use strings or chars, this will work.